# Sklearn Label Encoding multiple columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, encoding, scikit-learn

I try to encode a number of columns containing categorical data (`"Yes"` and `"No"`)  in a large pandas dataframe. The complete dataframe contains over 400 columns so I look for a way to encode all desired columns without having to encode them one by one. I use Scikit-learn `LabelEncoder` to encode the categorical data.

The first part of the dataframe does not have to be encoded, however I am looking for a method to encode all the desired columns containing categorical date directly without split and concatenate the dataframe.

To demonstrate my question I first tried to solve it on a small part of the dataframe. However get stuck at the last part where the data is fitted and transformed and get a `ValueError: bad input shape (4,3)`. The code as I ran:

```
# Create a simple dataframe resembling large dataframe
    data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                         'B': ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"],
                         'C': ["Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"],
                         'D': ["No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"]})


# Import required module
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Create an object of the label encoder class
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()

# Apply labelencoder object on columns
labelencoder.fit_transform(data.ix[:, 1:])   # First column does not need to be encoded
```

Complete error report:

```
labelencoder.fit_transform(data.ix[:, 1:])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-47-b4986a719976>", line 1, in <module>
    labelencoder.fit_transform(data.ix[:, 1:])

  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 129, in fit_transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

  File "C:\Anaconda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 562, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))

ValueError: bad input shape (4, 3)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Label encoder only supports single columns. You need to iterate your columns in order to encode them.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this and write a follow-up on the post

Answer (score 22):

As the following code, you can encode the multiple columns by applying `LabelEncoder` to DataFrame. However, please note that we cannot obtain the classes information for all columns.

```python
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"],
                   'C': ["Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"],
                   'D': ["No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"]})
print(df)
#    A    B    C    D
# 0  1  Yes  Yes   No
# 1  2   No   No  Yes
# 2  3  Yes   No   No
# 3  4  Yes  Yes  Yes

# LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()

# apply "le.fit_transform"
df_encoded = df.apply(le.fit_transform)
print(df_encoded)
#    A  B  C  D
# 0  0  1  1  0
# 1  1  0  0  1
# 2  2  1  0  0
# 3  3  1  1  1

# Note: we cannot obtain the classes information for all columns.
print(le.classes_)
# ['No' 'Yes']
```

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

and

    raise TypeError("argument must be a string or number")
TypeError: ('argument must be a string or number', 'occurred at index workclass')

Why is this considered a valid solution?

Comment: @VaidøtasIvøška I do not know your situation in detail, but please check if your data contains np.nan.

Comment: @Keiku is this the game-breaker? The np.nan? You mean if my dataset contains any **nan**'s then this error could occur? I will try this out asap.

Comment: My problem:
Traceback (most recent call last):
bla bla
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
and:
 raise TypeError("argument must be a string or number")
TypeError: ('argument must be a string or number'
I don't get it...

My example:
x = df.dropna()
catfm = x.dtypes==object
cat_cols = adult_train.columns[catfm].tolist()
df[categorical_cols] = adult_train[cat_cols].apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))

Comment: EDIT2: Now I get this:
Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only.
So this .apply works only with booleans?

Comment: @VaidøtasIvøška When I tried using only bool value with my data, it worked well.

Comment: I took a second look at my code and realized I had a mistake somewhere. Having changed a few things and adding a fillna(int) - now it works! Thanks, @Keiku! :)

Answer (score 5):

First, find out all the features with type object:

```
objList = all_data.select_dtypes(include = "object").columns
print (objList)
```

Now, to convert the above objList features into numeric  type, you can use a forloop as given below:

```
#Label Encoding for object to numeric conversion
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()

for feat in objList:
    df[feat] = le.fit_transform(df[feat].astype(str))

print (df.info())
```

Note that we are explicitly mentioning as type string in the forloop because if you remove that it throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

Scikit-learn has something for this now: [OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                         'B': ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"],
                         'C': ["Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"],
                         'D': ["No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"]})

oe = OrdinalEncoder()

t_data = oe.fit_transform(data)
print(t_data)
# [[0. 1. 1. 0.]
# [1. 0. 0. 1.]
# [2. 1. 0. 0.]
# [3. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Works straight out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the name of the columns and don't want to use all of them, you can do something like this (you are also getting rid of a for loop):

```
categ = ['Pclass','Cabin_Group','Ticket','Embarked']

# Encode Categorical Columns
le = LabelEncoder()
df[categ] = df[categ].apply(le.fit_transform)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
# df is the pandas dataframe
class preprocessing (BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
      def __init__ (self, df):
         self.datatypes = df.dtypes.astype(str)
         self.catcolumns = []
         self.cat_encoders = []
         self.encoded_df = []

      def fit (self, df, y = None):
          for ix, val in zip(self.datatypes.index.values, 
          self.datatypes.values):
              if val =='object':
                 self.catcolumns.append(ix)
          fit_objs = [str(i) for i in range(len(self.catcolumns))]
          for encs, name in zip(fit_objs,self.catcolumns):
              encs = LabelBinarizer()
              encs.fit(df[name])
              self.cat_encoders.append((name, encs))
          return self
      def transform (self, df , y = None): 
          for name, encs in self.cat_encoders:
              df_c = encs.transform(df[name])
              self.encoded_df.append(pd.DataFrame(df_c))
          self.encoded_df = pd.concat(self.encoded_df, axis = 1, 
          ignore_index 
          = True)
          self.df_num = df.drop(self.catcolumns, axis = 1)
          y = pd.concat([self.df_num, self.encoded_df], axis = 1, 
          ignore_index = True)
          return y        
# use return y.values to use in sci-kit learn pipeline
""" Finds categorical columns in a dataframe and one hot encodes the 
    columns. you can replace labelbinarizer with labelencoder if you 
    require only label encoding. Function returns encoded categorcial data 
    and numerical data as a dataframe """
```

Comment: Please avoid giving "code-only" answers, but instead explain your changes/methods and how they solve the OP's problem.

Comment: How do I include a description. I don't seem to understand the interface

Answer (score 1):

You can also loop through the different columns you want to apply the encoding to. This method might not the most efficient, but it works fine.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
LE = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = LE.fit(df[col])
    df[col] = LE.transform(df[col])
    test_data[col] = LE.transform(test_data[col])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the Simplest I could write:**

Step 1: Get all categorical columns:

```
categorical_columns = train.select_dtypes(['object']).columns
```

This will store all categorical columns.

Step2: Write a for loop to transform, as fit_transform only takes 1 index at a time. but here is the crack.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for col in train[categorical_columns]:
    train[col]= label_encoder.fit_transform(train[col])
```

Step3: Vote up lol :)

Hope you find this useful.