# While checking the model accuracy, i am getting error saying, " Bad Input shape(335427, 32)

Tags: python-3.x

I have created dummy variables using label encoder and i run my model but when i am checking accuracy of my model using K Fold and Cross validation i am getting Bad Input shape error. Please help to fix it

I have tried reshaping the model and also I have change my dummy variables creation using LabelEncoder

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

columns = df_train.drop('default_ind',axis =1).columns 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_train[columns], 
df_train, test_size = 0.3) 

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 

from sklearn.svm import SVC 

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier 

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB 

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 

models=[]

 models.append(("logreg",LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')))
 models.append(("tree",DecisionTreeClassifier())) 
 models.append(("forest",RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20))) 
 models.append(("svc",SVC())) 
 models.append(("knn",KNeighborsClassifier()))
 models.append(("nb",GaussianNB())) 
 seed=7 
 scoring='accuracy' 

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score 
result=[] 
names=[] 

for name,model in models: 
    kfold=KFold(n_splits=5,random_state=seed)
    cv_result=cross_val_score(model,X_train,y_train,cv=kfold,scoring=scoring) 
    result.append(cv_result) 
    names.append(name) 
print("%s %f %f" % (name,cv_result.mean(),cv_result.std()))
```

I am not able to check the accuracy and getting below error

> ValueError: bad input shape (335427, 32)

Answer (score 0):

Error message suggests that you are trying to pass more than one column (32 from error message) in `LabelEncoder()`? If yes then note that it supports single columns, you need to iterate your columns in order to encode them, see the answer at [Sklearn Label Encoding multiple columns pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474570/sklearn-label-encoding-multiple-columns-pandas-dataframe)