# Share label encoder over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to find an elegant way to label encode multiple columns in a **Pandas** dataframe with the same encoder. Suppose I have two columns that correspond to two-sport teams playing a match.

The solution that works for me is taking those two columns, converting to `numpy` array, flattening them, encoding, and then unflattening them and sticking them back into the dataframe. However, this seems to be more complicated than it should be, especially using the `pandas`+`scikitlearn` combination.

.

I will be happy with all the solutions, thanks in advance!

P.S. I want something similar to [the same shared encoder for columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60302366/13591234), but I don't want to install an external library just for this.

EDIT UPDATE:
I have tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57526317/10495893) suggested by [Ben Reiniger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10495893/ben-reiniger), but it is not what I want. More specifically:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],
'Name1':['Mary','Tom', 'Ricky', 'Steve'],})

oe = OrdinalEncoder()

t_data = oe.fit_transform(data)
```

The result I get is the following:

```
[[3. 0.]
 [0. 3.]
 [2. 1.]
 [1. 2.]]
```

For the data:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>Name</th>\n      <th>Name1</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>Tom</td>\n      <td>Mary</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1</th>\n      <td>Jack</td>\n      <td>Tom</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2</th>\n      <td>Steve</td>\n      <td>Ricky</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>3</th>\n      <td>Ricky</td>\n      <td>Steve</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
```

So as you can see Jack and Mary are encoded as the number - "0.0"
It means that the encoder takes all the columns individually.

The result I would like to have for this example is encoding all the columns as if they were one:

```
Jack - 0 
Mary - 1 
Ricky - 2 
Steve - 3 
Tom - 4
```

Even though Jack is only encountered in the first column and Mary in the second.

The resulting array should look like the following:

```
[[4. 1.]
 [0. 4.]
 [3. 2.]
 [2. 3.]]
```

Ideally, it should stay the `pandas dataframe`.

EDIT UPDATE 2:
My current code that works for me and I want to optimize is the following:

```
# data is Pandas dataframe
data = data.to_numpy()
X = data[:, [3, 4]] # I choose the columns that I want to encode
X = X.flatten()
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
X = label_encoder.fit_transform(X)
data[:, [3, 4]] = np.reshape(X, (-1, 2))
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=names)
```

Comment: Showing [reprex] with input data and expected output may help

Comment: Use `OrdinalEncoder` (and probably `ColumnTransformer`). This seems like a duplicate, but I can't search at the moment...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sklearn Label Encoding multiple columns pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474570/sklearn-label-encoding-multiple-columns-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Specifically, this answer is the best for newer versions of sklearn:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57526317/10495893

Comment: I have updated the post, please have a look at the examples

Answer (score 0):

You need to fit a LabelEncoder on the set of unique values, which you can find by finding each column's unique values and concatenating them:

```
name_uniques = data.Name.unique()
name1_uniques = data.Name1.unique()

uniques = np.unique(np.concatenate((name_uniques,name1_uniques),0))
```

Then you can fit your encoder on the uniques and transform your data:

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(uniques)

data.Name = label_encoder.transform(data.Name)
data.Name1 = label_encoder.transform(data.Name1)
```

Note that if it's actually sports teams, this method likely won't give you great results, because label encoding is giving the values ordinality where there isn't any.